# Using external url in ng-include in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-include

I have a problem in hand in AngularJS and need some pointers.

I have a view where I want to embed an external url (e.g. http://www.w3schools.com). The embeded html page should respond to events like click and touch like a normal html page.

I have used ng-include directive to get that working.

Here is a code snippet:

```
    <ion-content>
       <div ng-include src="'http://www.w3schools.com'"</div>
    </ion-content>
```

If I load the external html, I am getting the external webpage loaded, but all the links inside the page are broken. If I click on any link inside the loaded page, all links point to localhost now instead of the external url.

How can I fix this problem?

Thank in advance!

Comment: Hi, if the problem is because of cross-domain access, please let me know how can I fix it.

Comment: The links point to local host because the links were relative and not absolute urls meaning unless all the links on that page had the full url http://www.w3schools.com/about and not /about they will not work. It will look for /about on your server. This is not how include was meant to be used but if you did want to use it this way then you would need to create a custom directive that first does an $http.get of the url and then looks through the html and replaces all links to be absolute from the domain they came from.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Is there any other way I can embed an online html inside my page without changing the urls? I tried the iframe approach, but in an iframe, touch is not working.

Comment: no iframe is the only way to to maintain it's association with the domain and not have to rework the urls... Building a directive that would crawl the html and rewrite the links wouldn't be the end of the world. You could do it.

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like you really just want to host the external site inside your view, and then you should just link it in an iframe.

```
<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>
```

If you want something magic/dynamic stuff to happen, you will need to parse the content and rewrite the urls, attach handlers etc. The reason your ng-include does not work like expected is because it only reads the content of that url and embeds it into your view "as-if" it was just a template you made (including angular markup) and wanted to host externally for some reason.