# can we load an external angular site inside another angular site?

Tags: angularjs

Site1 and Site2 are built in angularjs. Whether do we have any concept in angularjs (except iframe) to load pages of Site2 inside a div of Site1 ? Incase if you have any examples, please share here. Thanks in advance.

[image: update 1]

Apart from the html content loaded from a external url (site2) to the source site (site1), there are lot of css and js files included in the site2 screens, whether that will also get loaded ?

Answer (score 5):

You can use

1) [ngInclude](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) Check documentation for usage

2) ng-bind-html, but you'll have to take care of [ngSanitize](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize). You have to put your html content in a special variable that is marked as trusted html. For this you have to use the $sce service.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

No need to specific angular tags, you can directly use object tag like this:

```
<div> 
    <object type="text/html" data="http://validator.w3.org/" width="800px" height="600px">
    </object>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

did u tried with `<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>`
the below url can help u
[Using external url in ng-include in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23367396/using-external-url-in-ng-include-in-angularjs)